# Remove underline in SSRS Link?

Tags: reporting-services

I created a link in a SSRS Report. I notice that if I using **Indent** und deactive the underline option that underlining is still there. Is this a bug?

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9UZ.png)

[and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGtu0.png)

[indent active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/923q9.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen when I create a link and use a Right Indent - I just tested it. Are you sure this isn't your browser adding the underline? Does it do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: It does not appear in the Preview mode of VS only in the browser. It only appear there if I use right ident without there are not underline in the link.

Comment: Does it appear in your broser after you add right indend of 5ppt?

Comment: AH - yes, I do get the underline in the browser when using any indent. This does seem to be a bug that's probably been there for decades. I suppose the workaround would be *Don't use indent with a link* - use padding instead. You can try submitting a bug report but they usually get closed as *Works as Designed*.

Comment: Its a weird bug. Only appear if you use right align. With padding the underline does not appear. Thanks. What is the difference between padding and indent? Looks like the same?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Padding then the link do not appear